# Apple network share - how do I restrict access for user or staff group?

Tags: macos, mac, network, permission, sharing

I have a Mac mini acting as a file share server with external hard drive as a 'shared drive'.

I have separate accounts for each user. Previously they were all in the same 'Team' group and could read and write every subfolder in the 'shared drive'.

However I have a new user that should only be able to access one subfolder, so I'd like to restrict permission for that user. However when I look at the info of the folder on the shared drive, there is no option to remove 'staff' group from permissions list.

If I create a folder on the system hard drive I can see the 'staff' group permission and can remove it. However on the external drive there is no option.

[image]

Edit: I figured out that I had 'Ignore ownership' enabled on the external drive which allowed any registered user to connect. I disabled this and re-enabled permissions on each subfolder which allowed me to finely control access.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -e /path/to/folder` because here acls and unix permissions are mixed and it's unclear which are which!

Comment: Hi, I've opened terminal and used ls -e to the folder, it just outputs a list of subfolders, should it do anything else?

Comment: sorry it's `ls -le /path/to/folder`

Comment: I usually use `ls -ale@ /path/to/folder` to view everything. Add the `-d` flag to just view the permissions of that folder and not its contents.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably change the group from staff to something else. Or remove the group access using:

```
chmod g-rwx /path/to/folder
```

Comment: I still want the folder accessible by my custom 'Team' group, just not accessible by any registered user - will chmod g-rwx remove both?

Comment: Oh, in that case just change the group ownership `chown :groupname /path/to/folder` and then remove 'everyone' permissions `chmod o-rwx /path/to/folder`